# Can I use full PostgreSQL functions on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

AgensGraph is multi-model database based on PostgreSQL. 
The thing what I wonder is, so can I use the PostgreSQL function 
like abs(), go_dist() with graph data? 
If so, is there something to set configurations for that?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't trust the result, it's true or false value. The result was popup as I use pg_hint_plan,